# Circuitikz bipole: auto length

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to declare a bipole in Circuitikz which changes its length automatically based on the coordinates. MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[european,strokediode]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/length=5mm}

\makeatletter
% used to process styles for to-path
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}
% restore size value for bipole definitions
\pgf@circ@Rlen = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
\makeatother

\newlength{\ResUp} \newlength{\ResDown}
\newlength{\ResLeft} \newlength{\ResRight}



\ctikzset{bipoles/mstline/height/.initial=.30}
\ctikzset{bipoles/mstline/width/.initial=1.80}
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/mstline/height}}
{mstline}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/mstline/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/mstline/width}}
{
\pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
\pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\northeast}
\pgfextractx{\ResLeft}{\southwest}
\pgfextracty{\ResDown}{\southwest}
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}
\pgfusepath{draw}
}
\def\speakerpath#1{\TikzBipolePath{mstline}{#1}}
\tikzset{mstline/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\speakerpath, l=#1}}


\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [mstline] ++(40mm,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Now I want the bipole `mstline` to be 40mm in width, and if I change these 40mm to, say, 50mm, the symbol should also be 50mm in width. Is such a thing possible, and how? I tried around a bit but didn't find it out.

Comment: The size of a component in a schematic generally stays the same no matter what.  AFAIK, the component definition has no way to know how far the wires stretch.  You can adjust the size manually on an individual basis, but not automatically.

Comment: OTOH, you can use a tikz decoration in a circuitikz schematic.